# How to load location before main view controller loads?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Let me just say I'm still an Objective-C/iOS noob, I haven't been learning it that long, so please excuse my ignorance :)

The content of my app changes based on the user's location.  I would prefer the `"ThisApp" would like to use your current location` dialogue to appear before any content is loaded, to avoid the content having to reload.

I noticed that some apps seem to have that location popup appear while still on the launch image page (the page that shows Default.png).  I did a lot of Googling but couldn't find anything (probably because I didn't know the correct terminology).

The way I implemented this was to have my app go to my LocationViewController first, this only contains default code, no changes, and in the storyboard it just has an image view with the Default.png in.  Then I have a segue from the location controller (LocationViewControllerSegue) to the main view controller.

My AppDelegate.h looks like so:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>  {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

And my AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (locationManager == nil)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 16000;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    return YES;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    [self.window.rootViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LocationViewControllerSegue" sender:self.window.rootViewController];
}

... snip a bunch of default generated code ...

@end
```

1. Is there a better way to do this, than my illusionary location view controller method?
2. If this is a reasonable way to get what I want, is there somewhere better I could place the performSegueWithIdentifier than in the locationManager?  It seems like a bad place to put it (and not sure if it will cause issues further along in the app?), but moving it either into the LocationViewController or into didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: stops it from working.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.  Thanks :)

Comment: didUpdateToLocation will be called several times, as the name suggest, you should just get the current coordinates of the location. you should not call any other method init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a fairly hacky method, but one that might work. About the only thing I'd recommend for this particular method would be to have `locationManager` ***stop*** updating the location once you've found what you need (`[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]`). Otherwise, as `sree charan` noted, you'll get a bunch of calls to `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` that will then generate a ton of calls to `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`.

As an aside, I think I might rather do this location update in your LocationViewController rather than the app delegate, but it likely has more to do with style than substance.

Comment: And it's a style I like, so I've moved it :)  Many thanks for the locationManager code, I noticed the location being checked a few times in my log, but wasn't sure what to do about it.  And I'll keep an eye out for a better (less hacky) method to do what I want to do in the future, but this will suffice for now :)  Thanks.